# regex help, only one hyphen in a row?

Tags: regex

I want to accept `0-9` `,` and `-`

So I have:

```
[0-9-,]+
```

However I only want there to be ever one `-` in a  row, so you can't have `--`. How can I do this?

Comment: Do you want to accept the comma or not? Because your regex currently does accept it.

Comment: writing comma was a mistake sorry.

Comment: I've asked and turns out a comma is needed. so that I can add 1-2, 3-4 etc

Comment: So, would `1,,,2-,-3,4-5-6,` be allowed? If not, please specify *exactly*  what should and what should not be allowed to match. (How about spaces? Shouldn't `1-2, 3-4` be allowed to match?)

Comment: Sorry I am not being specific at all Tim. I am basically accepting ranges for vlans. So I wouldn't want several commas, and I don't need a space that was a typo. I can accept things like 4 or 4-5 or 4,4-5. Why i did not mention this is because if the user types ,,, my code already catches it without the need for it to be in the regex however for -- the console thinks I am using a command so I need to filter it in the regex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think required one is this:

```
^\d+(-\d+)?(,\d+(-\d+)?)*$
```

What this does is:

`\d+` any integer (one or more digits)

`(-\d+)?` optional part matching a `-` followed by an integer

`(,\d+(-\d+)?)*` zero or more occurrence of a `,` followed by combination of above mentioned patterns.

**Note:** Add required escaping for `\`

Comment: +1 I think that's the best possible regex if lookaheads are not supported (which may be the case here).

Comment: Thanks naveed, I'm trying this and it looks good. i'm just not sure why nothing is being accepted at all now. makes no sense. Not even a single number.

Comment: eg: switch(config-if)# switchport trunk allowed vlan 9                              
Syntax error: Illegal parameter

Comment: I am not sure what the ? is doing here, I need to read about this more. With this regex is it possible to just add a single integer?

Comment: @Paul Of course. `?` makes the preceding part i.e. `(-\d+)` optional making it possible to allow single integer only

Comment: Ah ok I thought so. I'll try and see why nothing at all is ebing acceptwd with this regex. thanks.

Comment: I dont think it likes \d. i tried \d+ on it's own and that doesnt work

Comment: @Paul problem will be with escaping. Try `\\d+` instead of `\d+`

Comment: @Paul I don't know why `\d` is not accepted. So replace each `\d` in my answer with `[0-9]` and try

Comment: This works thanks, ^[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?(,[0-9]+(-[0-9]+)?)*$ You are a great help.

Comment: @NaveedS: POSIX regular expressions don't know the `\d` shorthand.

Comment: @TimPietzcker that was unknown to me. Thanks for the info.

Comment: That's useful, I was wondering why certain things just wouldn't work.

Answer (score 2):

Use a [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
(?!.*--)[0-9,-]+
```

Also, you might need to use [anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) to ensure that the entire string is matched:

```
^(?!.*--)[0-9,-]+$
```

Comment: This seems to cause an error in my system for some reason. If I add it to my code I cant use the program at all.

Comment: Which system are you using (you should always add a corresponding tag to any regex question as per the FAQ).

Comment: Actually it is fine to accept 3- or - or 3 because my code deals with those cases

Comment: @Paul: That looks like a Unix shell extension or something similar. And the standard Unix (POSIX) tools don't support lookaheads.

Answer (score 0):

is this ok ?

```
^[0-9,]*-?[0-9,]*$
```

just did a small test with grep:

```
kent$  echo "1-234-
1234-
3-24442-34
12341234"|grep -E '^[0-9,]*-?[0-9,]*$'
1234-
12341234
```

Comment: That allows only one dash, where multiple (just not consecutive) are required.

Comment: @TimPietzcker that is what he wanted, isn't it? or I misunderstood the question...